# Power Query - How to load certain rows of a column into the Buffer according to conditions

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have to replicate a series of steps to many files. These files are loaded into power query as a table named "main". Column 1 is an index, and columns 2 and 3 have variable names depending on the files.

On the other hand I have a table called CLDR that has three columns: Character, Category and Languages. One of the Category column values ​​is "Main Letters".

In a blank query I want to buffer the following:

1. Second.Letters = Rows of the column "Character", in which the name of the second column of "main" is included in the column "Languages", and the Category section is equal to "Main Letters".
2. Second.Simbols = Rows of the column "Character", in which the name of the second column of "main" is included in the column "Languages", and the Category section is different from "Main Letters".
3. Third.Letters = Rows of the column "Character", in which the name of the third column of "main" is included in the column "Languages", and the Category section is equal to "Main Letters"
4. Third.Simbols = Rows of the column "Character", in which the name of the third column of "main" is included in the column "Languages", and the Category section is equal to "Main Letters"

I attach the files here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uxFMcvqB6lTS7OCb_YF7_iD6A-jqa1Nx?usp=sharing

Sorry if I'm asking for something too complicated.

Comment: Instead of using M, you might consider Python: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-in-query-editor. There you have all the flexibility to pivot data into new columns according to filter conditions. You simply need to pass a DataFrame.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not a programmer, I just struggle a bit with power query. That is not to say that your suggestion is not good. Maybe if I had some accessible guide on how to do that I would dabble in python. Although this is probably the only job where I need python and learning it is not very profitable.

Comment: You could also start with generating M code generated by your visual actions. Just filter a column and have a look what is the equivalent M for that in the M editor. Learn step by step what is needed. Also check the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-pivot where you pivot into columns on the base on a condition. That should already give you the M code to a large part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've assumed that for point 4, where you say:

> Third.Simbols = ... and the Category section is equal to "Main Letters"

you instead meant:

> Third.Simbols = ... and the Category section is **not equal** to "Main Letters"

If my assumption is wrong, in `Third.Symbols`, you'll just need to change the `<>` to `=`.

---

Try copy-pasting the code below into your `Buffer` query -- and see if it gives you the output you're expecting.

```
let
    mainColumnNames = Table.ColumnNames(main),
    Second.Letters = Table.SelectRows(CLDR, each "Main Letters" = [Category]  and Text.Contains([Languages], mainColumnNames{1})),
    Second.Symbols = Table.SelectRows(CLDR, each [Category] <> "Main Letters" and Text.Contains([Languages], mainColumnNames{1})),
    Third.Letters = Table.SelectRows(CLDR, each "Main Letters" = [Category]  and Text.Contains([Languages], mainColumnNames{2})),
    Third.Symbols = Table.SelectRows(CLDR, each [Category] <> "Main Letters" and Text.Contains([Languages], mainColumnNames{2}))
in
    Third.Symbols
```

---

Currently, when filtering the `Languages` column (of `CLDR` table) for some particular language (e.g. `.en`), the search/comparison is case-sensitive and textual. The implications of this are:

1. a row containing `.EN` will not be considered a match (as the comparison is case-sensitive and needs to match `.en` exactly).
   *(If you don't want this behaviour, this can be solved by using something like `Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` which will ignore case when comparing.)*
2. a row like `.fr.ent.de.se` will match (the comparison won't care that the "language" is `.ent` and not `.en`, as it's only looking for `.en` *anywhere* within the string).
   *(If this is a problem for you, one way to solve this by might be to split the value by `.` and then individually check each of `fr`, `ent`, `de`, `se` for a case-(in)sensitive match for `en`.)*

---

Sidenote: I don't know what your situation is but if you have many files similar to `main.csv` and `CLDR.csv`, you might want to make use of `Folder.Files` and also create a function that accepts two tables (`main` and `CLDR`), which can be reused.

Comment: THANK YOU! that was exactly what I was looking for, even more, you exceeded what I had asked for. You exceeded my expectations. Thank you.